# Only show data on html page where javascript date is within last 10 days

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime

I have javascript array in which the date coming in is in this format

```
 2015-11-25T17:54:19.033
```

However, I am not really concerned with the time

so I end up with

```
 11/25/15
```

What I want to do in my loop is to LOOK at the date ( either 2015-11-25T17:54:19.033 or 11/25/15  , whatever is easier)  and just set a variable to "NEW" if it is within the last 10 days

I was attempted to play around with this code and it does not give me what I want at all

```
var dt = "11/25/15";

var today = new Date()
var priorDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate()-10)

console.log(dt);
console.log(today);
console.log(priorDate);
```

pseudo code of what i WANT

```
if ( dt <= today ) {  
   x = "NEW";
}
```

So my thoughts are that it need to be in Date objects in javascript but i'm not sure

Update

So say in a loop i have these variables that occur

for ....
 dt = 9/13/15

Output  =    9/13/15

next time in loop

dt =  11/24/15

Output =  NEW - 11/24/15

Working jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/yr009hwd/

Comment: Can you be more explicit?  What about your pseudo code is not working?

Comment: In your code, are you creating a Date out of your string?
 new Date(dt);

Comment: I'm just displaying the date on html as say  11/25/15   , but If it is   9/13/15   I don't want to should the word "NEW"  next to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. You need to convert the string date to a date time object in javascript to do the comparison.In order to do the comparison, you need to get the millisec of the dates using `getTime()`

```
 var dt = new Date("11/22/2015");
var today = new Date();
if ( dt.getTime() < today.getTime() ) {  
  alert('Past');
}
else
    alert('future');
```

To check if the date difference is within 10 days:

```
   var dt = new Date("11/12/2015");
var today = new Date();
var dateDiffDays = Math.ceil((Math.ceil(dt.getTime() - today.getTime()))/(1000 * 3600 * 24));
if( dateDiffDays >= -10 && dateDiffDays <= 10)
    alert('date within 10 days');
```

Comment: If they are Date objects, you can just compare them without using getTime()

Comment: Wait ,  I need to know the date within last 10 days

Comment: works  thx,   i made a fiddle  in put in the question    http://jsfiddle.net/bthorn/yr009hwd/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of your date string, you can probably just do:

```
var dateToTest = new Date(dt);

//get 10 days earlier
dateToTest.setDate(dateToTest.getDate() - 10);

var today = new Date();
if ( dateToTest < today ) {  
    x = 'NEW';
}

//see if a date is within the last 10 days

var tenDaysAgo = new Date(); //current date
tenDaysAgo.setDate(tenDaysAgo.getDate() - 10); //ten days ago
//if you don't care about the time
tenDaysAgo.setHours(0);
tenDaysAgo.setMinutes(0);
tenDaysAgo.setSeconds(0);
tenDaysAgo.setMilliseconds(0);

var someDateToTest = new Date('11-1-2015');
if (tenDaysAgo > someDateToTest) {
   //this is new
   x = 'NEW';
}
```

Comment: i need date with last 10 days

Comment: you can use the date's setDate() method to set it equal to 10 days earlier by using date.setDate(date.getDate() - 10); I updated my answer to include this.

Comment: Maybe we don't understand the problem you have exactly. Are you trying to see if a date you have is more recent than 10 days ago?

Comment: sorry i didn't get a chance to test your edited answer in time as i tested the other updated solution in a jsfiddle and posted it ,  thx